# API Gateway Encoding multipart/form-data

Tags: amazon-web-services, form-data, gateway

I have a beanstalk reflected in my API gateway with passthrough, where my client sends a direct multipart/form-data request to beanstalk. The image sends correctly and I can open it normally, but when I make the request from the API Gateway, I can't open the image. Looks like the API Gateway encode messes up the image content when performing the passthrough to beanstalk.

How I can set the API Gateway encode or make a pure passthrough?

Answer (score 0):

You can add multipart/form-data to Binary mediatype (go to the settings page of your API gateway api definition). This will encode image with Base64. You can decode the image text then