# Angular 2 Image Upload Corruption

Tags: angular, file-upload, image-uploading, angular2-forms

I have created the following service for uploading files to a server in Angular2:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http'
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class UploadService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    public upload(url: string, file: File, type: string): Observable<Response>{
        let formData: FormData = new FormData()
        formData.append("uploadFile", file);
        let headers = new Headers(); 
        headers.append('Content-Type', type);
        let opts:RequestOptionsArgs = { headers: headers };
        return this.http.put(url, formData, opts)
    }
}
```

It works fine for most data types, except I am having a bizarre problem where for images it adds the following header into the top of the file:

------WebKitFormBoundaryUmPd3GQyQ1XQfCFv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadFile"; filename="Picture_Lotus-01.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

Other than that all the data has been uploaded correctly; i.e if i then download the file and remove those header lines the image is readable. I have tested the upload with Postman and it works fine, therefore I believe it is the way that I'm configuring the header information in my angular2 upload.
Help!! I have been banging my head against this for a whole day now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is standard for multipart/form-data and I needed an adequate parser server-side.

Comment: I have the exact same issue as you - are you able to say what server-side parser you used please?

Comment: @Mike Hey sorry this was so long ago I honestly can't remember, but depending on what framework you're using server side there are different packages - for express https://github.com/expressjs/multer#readme. I was using AWS and this was helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756190/api-gateway-post-multipart-form-data