# Api Gateway. Binary with Form Data

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I am having a hard time trying to get a grasp on API Gateway Binary Support. How do I send upload a file together with a textual form data in a single multipart/form-data POST?

Comment: Where is the file being uploaded to after being received by API Gateway?

Comment: I'm uploading to Lambda in the following format... { "bucket": "EXAMPLE-BUCKET", "data": "EXAMPLE-DATA" }. Lambda will then upload the data to the required S3 bucket

Comment: API Gateway doesn't parse or interpret the `multipart/form-data` structures... you'd have to parse the fields from the request body, after decoding it from base64, inside the Lambda function. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41770688/1695906

Answer (score 1):

Have you added `multipart/form-data` as one of the `Binary Media Types` in the API Gateway configuration (In the "Settings" tab)?

AWS API Gateway handles both binary data and text data and `multipart/form-data` is one of the binary data types.

The key thing you need to do is to leverage the `Content-Type` header, which is `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; <boundary XXX>`, to tell the gateway to handle your payload as binary data. After having `multipart/form-data` as one of the `Binary Media Types`, you just need to read the payload as a multipart form and there are plenty of libs that do this.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html