# How do I access a POST parameter in Node js AWS Lambda with API Gateway integration?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I know how to access GET string variables in a Node js Lambda that is integrated with API Gateway with:

```
 event["queryStringParameters"]["variable_name"]
```

What is the equivalent for accessing POST variables?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the following

```
if (event.body !== null && event.body !== undefined) {
        let body = JSON.parse(event.body) //use in case of JSON body
        //your code
}
```

[AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html)

Comment: I'm unsure why this answer was downvoted, but it is correct. When you receive a POST in your Lambda handler from API Gateway, the Lambda event contains a field called `body` which contains a JSON string representation of the POST body. You can parse the JSON into an object and access your POST variables as keys in the body object.

Comment: Thx. Json parse didn't work for me but the rest got me in the right track

Comment: @jaimerr you need to make sure your body is valid in json format

Comment: Your body will be whatever you post to it.  If you post multipart form data, JSON parse will tank.  That's probably why it is getting downvoted.

Comment: I am using JSON. parse & there is no multi-part data. event. the body is resulting in an unexpected JSON.

Comment: @PreetSaxena Above code example is for when the posted body is in JSON format. You can get an idea about multipart data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756190/api-gateway-post-multipart-form-data)

Comment: Thank you, it was working. I was expecting that it will work the same as mock events but it didn't so we need to follow the multipart concept.