# File being corrupt when upload using multer node js

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I implemented the [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) upload example on restful using [express](https://expressjs.com/).
The following code is the server code.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, './files/')
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
          crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function (err, raw) {
            cb(null, raw.toString('hex') + Date.now() + '.xsd');
          });
        }
});

var cpUpload = multer({ storage: storage, limits: {fileSize: 1000000}}).single('schema-file');

var app = express(); 
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS');
        next();
});

app.post('/ws-api-designer-upload-files', cpUpload, function (req, res, next) {

        console.log("filepath " + req.file.filename);
        cpUpload(req,res,function(err){

            if(err){
                res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                res.end(JSON.stringify({
                    status: 'ERROR 1',
                    description: err.message
                }));
                return;
            }else{
                res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                res.end(JSON.stringify({
                    status: 'SUCCESS 1',
                    description: 'success'
                }));
                return;             
            }
        });

});
```

But when i call this service using postman, the file are uploaded but when i compare original file between uploaded file, the uploaded file corrupted. I'm struggling on this problem for almost 1 week, please help.

Note that this problem comes when code running on windows server 2008 r2. So when i run this server code on localhost there was no any problem like corrupted file. And I only upload a xsd file which is 173kb in size.

This one is uploaded file (corrupt)
[uploaded file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URapv.png)

This one is original file
[original file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfGg0.png)

Comment: anyone please help

Comment: Did you ever discover the cause of this? I think I may be experiencing the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/50989630/304832

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet. Even when i submit this one to their issue. https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/595, by the way how about you? Have any idea?

Comment: No, so I just offered a bounty on my question. Thanks for the reply @dityagow

Comment: you aren't hosting this code in an AWS lambda, are you?

Comment: Yes it is. Just self hosted. Is it different? Or still on same context of problem?

Comment: if you are using api gateway, that may be what is messing up the payload before it even makes it to express https://stackoverflow.com/a/41770688/304832. hope that helps?

Comment: We found a temporary workaround -- using `FileReader` to transform the binary file to base64, then submit that as text.

Comment: Do you mean to convert file as binary? Then send it?