# Receive and send multipart/form-data file in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm trying to do a `multipart/form-data` POST containing a pdf file to an AWS lambda function, do a few checks on the file and then POST the file to an external API.

I'm using the serverless framework with node.js and the [aws-lambda-multipart-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-lambda-multipart-parser) plugin to receive the file.

The file upload from the client to lambda works, and I can print the buffer content to the console. The part that does not work is the forwarding of the file to an external API.

This is my current axios setup to make a POST request to the external API:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file.content, file.filename);

const res = await axios.post(`https://external-api.com`, formData, {
  headers: { ...formData.getHeaders(), "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
  params: {
    someParams: foo
  }
});
```

`file.content` actually contains a Buffer with the file content, but when I make the request, the external API returns an error and the request fails...

Interestingly, the whole setup works when I run the serverless function locally with `sls offline`. That may suggest that there is a problem with the API Gateway setup.

**Some additional info:**

Based on the [instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-lambda-multipart-parser) from the multipart plugin I added the binary data type in the API Gateway settings:

[image]

This is the config of the endpoint in AWS Gateway:

[image]

I also tried this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756190/api-gateway-post-multipart-form-data) and the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html), but they only cover how to receive a binary file, not how to send one.

**Is it possible to receive and then send a file in lambda, or should this be solved in a different way?**

Comment: What is the file size which gets submitted via the form?

Comment: I'm testing with a file that is 187,0 kB

Comment: Yes that file can be received and sent also

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with that library. So I tried with - https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-multipart-parser - there is also a description of what to write in `serverless.yml` file. It is working like charm now!