# Wrap JPEG image in a multipart header using AWS Lambda@Edge

Tags: amazon-web-services, multipart

I have been trying to read the AWS Lambda@Edge [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-access-request-body-examples), but I still cannot figure out if the following option is possible.

Assume I have an object (image.jpg, with size 32922 bytes) and I have setup AWS as static website. So I can retrieve:

```
$ GET http://example.com/image.jpg
```

I would like to be able to also expose:

```
$ GET http://example.com/image
```

Where the response body would be a `multipart/related` file (for example). Something like this :

```
--myboundary
Content-Type: image/jpeg;
Content-Length: 32922
MIME-Version: 1.0

<actual binary jpeg data from 'image.jpg'>
--myboundary
```

Is this something supported out of the box in the AWS Lambda@Edge API ? or should I use another solution to create such response ? In particular it seems that the response only deal with [text or base64](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-generating-http-responses-in-requests.html#lambda-generating-http-responses-object) (I would need binary in my case).

Comment: Although not clear on that page, I think the base64 encoding _is_ for sending binary data. The whole response is going to be passed between Lambda and CloudFront in a text format like JSON, so you have to encode that data somehow _internally_; CloudFront will immediately decode it again and serve the actual binary data. Not very efficient, but simpler to implement than an actual binary protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to find complete documentation. I eventually stumble upon:

- [API Gateway - PORT multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756190/api-gateway-post-multipart-form-data)

which refers to:

- [Enabling binary support using the API Gateway console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html)

The above documentation specify the steps to handle binary data. Pay attention that you need to base64 encode the response from lambda to pass it to API Gateway.