# Why do I get a blank pdf when uploaded on S3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I upload a `pdf` `blob` object to S3

```
      const params = {
        Bucket: "poster-print-bucket",
        Key: Date.now().toString() + ".pdf",
        Body: blob,
        contentType: "application/pdf",
      };

      const uploaded = await S3.upload(params).promise();
```

When I open a url which is i.e https://poster-print-bucket.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/1633526785678.pdf
It downloads me a blank pdf

I thought maybe my `blob` is corrupted or something but I managed to upload same `blob` to firebase storage just fine.

btw I'm using nextjs `api/upload-poster` route

What's happening?

Comment: Have you tried converting blob to base64? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650168/convert-blob-to-base64

Comment: Error
`Failed to load PDF document.`

When opening the url

Comment: Throw the `ContentMD5` on there to also validate that it is actually getting uploaded. You probably want a `try/catch` as well to make sure there isn't an error and that the upload is actually completing before continuing.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ContentMD5. How it can help to validate if it is uploaded? I see it in my S3 bucket that it is uploaded. Also file size seem to be what I expect but that pdf being blank is something that is very strange

Answer (score 2):

I spent more time fixing this issue than I would like to admit.
Here is the solution:

Frontend (converting blob to base64 before sending to backend):

```
            function toBase64(blob) {
              const reader = new FileReader();
              return new Promise((res, rej) => {
                reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
                reader.onload = function () {
                  res(reader.result);
                };
              });
            }

            toBase64(currentBlob)
              .then((blob) => {
                return axios
                  .post("/api/upload-poster", blob, {
                    headers: {
                      "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
                    },
                  })
                  .then(({ data }) => data.uploaded.Location);
              })
```

Backend:

```
      const base64 = req.body;
      const base64Data = Buffer.from(base64.replace(/^data:application\/\w+;base64,/, ""), "base64");
     
      const params = {
        Bucket: "poster-print-bucket",
        Key: nanoid() + ".pdf",
        Body: base64Data,
        ContentEncoding: "base64",
        contentType: "application/pdf",
      };

      const uploaded = await S3.upload(params).promise();
```

Why this all song and dance is required? Can it be something easier?

Answer (score 2):

Using the AWS SDK v3 (up-to-date at the time of this post), you could use [PutObjectCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/putobjectcommand.html) which accepts a Uint8Array as `Body` params ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/interfaces/putobjectcommandinput.html)).

Convert your Blob instance to an ArrayBuffer ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer)), and your ArrayBuffer to an Uint8Array.

Code would look like:

```js
const { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');
const client = new S3Client(/* config */);

const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
const typedArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
await client.send(new PutObjectCommand({
   Bucket: /* ... */,
   Key: /* ... */,
   Body: typedArray,
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from the AWS API Gateway configuration which is not configured by default to pass binary data.

By following these resources, I found a solution:

- [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756190/api-gateway-post-multipart-form-data)
- [Enabling binary support using the API Gateway console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html)
- [Working with binary media types for REST APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html)

If you are using cdk:

```js
    /* "this" refers to your stack object */
    const api = new RestApi(this, `my-api-gateway-name`, {
        /* ... your rest of configuration */
        binaryMediaTypes: ['*/*'],
    });

    const integration = new LambdaIntegration(handler, {
        /* ... your rest of configuration */
        contentHandling: ContentHandling.CONVERT_TO_BINARY,
        passthroughBehavior: PassthroughBehavior.WHEN_NO_MATCH,
    });

    api.root.addProxy({
        defaultIntegration: integration,
        anyMethod: true,
    });
```

If you are not using cdk go to API Gateways, find your api and set these configuration there.