# Nodejs upload file to S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm using Serverless Framework with AWS Lambda to upload files/images to S3. The data come from a multipart/form-data form so I get file(s) in binary format.

[Example of POST request from REST client (Insomnia)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twOuH.png)

Upload to S3 code :

```ts
this.client
    .putObject({
        Bucket: s3bucket,
        Key: s3path,
        Body: Buffer.from(data, 'binary'),
        ContentType: params.mimetype
    })
    .promise();
```

The problem is files or images uploaded to S3 are corrupted :

> The image "http://xxxxx.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/xxx cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

I already set binaryMediaTypes in my Serverless file config for api gateway :

```ts
apiGateway: {
  binaryMediaTypes: ['*/*'],
},
```

and the same in AWS API Gateway Binary Media Types config, I set * / * when * / * means all media types

[API Gateway Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRJ1Y.png)

Have you ever encountered this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

1. In the integration request check if the `content handling: passthrough`
2. Accept the incoming request headers in `HTTP Headers` section.
   [Refer this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html)

[Related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756190/api-gateway-post-multipart-form-data)